# SSMS connection to Database kills VS connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I created a small project in Visual Studio 16.0.3 and created a SQLExpress database.  Connections and migrations all worked fine.

I then opened the database in SSMS 17.5 and am able to see and manipulate data.

But when I go back to Visual Studio I can see the database in SQL Server Object Explorer, but can't connect to it.

I have done the following:
Detached the database from SSMS
Closed SSMS
Restarted VS
Restarted the computer
Stop and restarted SQLExpress in the Task Manager

After all this I can still use the db in SSMS but can't get to it in VS.

I'd like to be able to connect both ways.  Any ideas appreciated.

**Edit**
Here is the app_config, I am using localhost.   This is just a local db for my own use, I usually use update-database -script on databases other people are using so this is how I've been doing it. Can you tell me how the connection string should be set up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
         AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\db.mdf;
         Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Edit 2**
I changed the connection string as shown below and it now works.  Had to add a new connection in SQL object explorer.

```
<add name="context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;
    Database=db;Integrated Security=True;
    Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
    MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
```

Comment: SSMS doesn't kill connections to databases. No DBA would be able to connect to any server if that were true. Are you using [User instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sql-server-express-user-instances) databases perhaps? Those are essentially single-user instances. What does your connnection string look like? Does it contain an `AttachDbFilename` key?

Comment: edit above showing config

Comment: `AttachDbFilename` - that's a user instance database. It allows only one user and actually runs only as long as there's a connection to it

Comment: edit above showing revised connection string that works.  Another stupid mistake on my end.  Thanks for the help @PanagiotisKanavos